# C++ char[100] = "hello" doesn't work

Tags: c++

Is there a better, shorter, easier to read version of the following code:

```
char ar[100];

int main() {
    //ar = "hello"; doesn't compile
    ar[0] = 'h';
    ar[1] = 'e';
    ar[2] = 'l';
    ar[3] = 'l';
    ar[4] = 'o';
    ar[5] = '\x00';
    return 0;
}
```

Note: The type of `ar` has to be `char[100]`.
The "real" program is:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdarg>

#define TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE 100

char toStringBuf[TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE];

std::string toCptr_(const char * format, ...) {
  va_list argzeiger;
  va_start(argzeiger, format);
  int16_t ret = vsnprintf(toStringBuf, TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE, format, argzeiger);
  if(ret >= TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE - 1) {
    //toStringBuf = "buffer too small";
  } else if(ret < 0) {
    //toStringBuf = "encoding error";
  }
  va_end(argzeiger);
  std::string returning(toStringBuf);
  return returning;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?  The dummy code or your actual code?  If the actual code has a problem where and what is it?

Comment: `ar = "hello"` is a syntax error.  Try `strcpy`

Comment: "The type of ar has to be char[100]" Only if your professor or TA says so, otherwise there's no reason to use a bare char array.

Comment: Totally agree about the professor TA saying this to you as a "reason" (in quotes as you see).  Or the other reason is that you just believe that you can only do whatever you want to do with a char array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `strncpy()`, eg:

```
strncpy(toStringBuf, str_buf, TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE);
toStringBuf[TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE-1] = 0;
```

Don't use `strcpy()`, as it is one of the most classically well-known unsafe functions in C/C++.  It can write past the end of the buffer, causing buffer overflow errors.  Not a problem in your particular example, but it should still be avoided in general.

Comment: This is bad advice. See [here](http://blog.liw.fi/posts/strncpy/), among other places. The `strncpy` function was meant for fixed-length structures inside other structures, not for C-style strings.

Comment: i agree that c strings are crappy as the article implies, but strncpy is still better than just strcpy. that's like saying you should not use a seatbelt because only airbags are safe. seat belts are still better than no seat belt.

Comment: Thank you, but shouldn't it be strncpy(str2, str1, str2bufsize) instead of len(str1)?
In my example:  strncpy(toStringBuf, "buffer too small", TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE) ;

Comment: @Julius Your answer is being read by someone who doesn't know how to use `strcpy`. They're not going to get that nuance unless you tell them.

Comment: So when copying that error message with `strncpy`, if the buffer is too small you get an unterminated string. How, exactly, is that "safe"?

Comment: it's better than allowing a user to overwrite the memory outside of the bounds of the buffer. it just crashes, instead of allowing the user to place arbitrary bits into your (server's?) memory

Comment: also Pete Becker, the constant string was edited in by a mod

Comment: & I added a null character at the end

Answer (score 6):

Use the `strcpy` function to copy a C-style string.

```
strcpy(ar, "hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you can use `strcpy()`/`strncpy()` to copy a string into a `char[]` buffer.

However, that is not actually necessary in this example.  Your function returns a `std::string`, so you don't actually need a `char[]` at all.  It is a waste of memory for short messages, a limitation for long messages, and a thread-unsafe condition (unless you use a local buffer instead of a global buffer).  Try this instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdarg>

std::string toCptr_(const char * format, ...)
{
    std::string str;

    va_list argzeiger;
    va_start(argzeiger, format);

    int ret = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, argzeiger);
    if (ret < 0) {
        str = "encoding error";
    }
    else {
        str.resize(ret+1);
        vsnprintf(&str[0], str.size(), format, argzeiger);
        str.resize(ret);
    }

    va_end(argzeiger);

    return str;
}
```

Or, at the very least:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdarg>

#define TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE 100

std::string toCptr_(const char * format, ...)
{
    char toStringBuf[TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE];
    std::string str;

    va_list argzeiger;
    va_start(argzeiger, format);

    int ret = vsnprintf(toStringBuf, TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE, format, argzeiger);
    if (ret < 0) {
        str = "encoding error";
    }
    else if (ret < TO_STRING_BUF_SIZE) {
        str.assign(toStringBuf, ret);
    }
    else {
        str.resize(ret+1);
        vsnprintf(&str[0], str.size(), format, argzeiger);
        str.resize(ret);
    }

    va_end(argzeiger);

    return str;
}
```